# Derby Network Server not started automatically

Tags: database, derby, in-memory, razorsql

I my application, file 'apache.jndi.properties' contains

```
DS.JdbcDriver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

DS.JdbcUrl=jdbc:derby:memory:derbyDB;create=true;derby.drda.startNetworkServer=true
```

The Network server not started automatically regarding above configs, but it started programmatically when i try below code

```
new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),1527).start(null)
```

what's wrong with apache.jndi.properties and why it is not started automatically?

Comment: Where did you read that there was something called `apache.jndi.properties`? That's not a Derby thing...

Comment: I put "derby.drda.startNetworkServer=true" in derby.properties and it worked! Thanks Bryan! But RazorSql still can not connect to database in debug mode! when I resume the execution of the code (removing from debug mode) or execute Thread,sleep(x) it connects!

Comment: To clarify: you run your app under a Java debugger, and find that the Network Server that is run by your app is not responsive when your app is halted and under the control of the debugger? If I've got it correct, it seems like you should open a **new** question for discussion of that issue, as it's quite separate from this one.